# Alternative Database Gateway for Oracle Express Edition 18c to connect to MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle18c

I am looking for suggestions on alternatives of connecting Oracle Express Edition 18c to a Microsoft SQL Database via a DB Link since Database Gateways are not enabled on Express Edition

Thanks
Edwin

Comment: You could connect the SQL Server to the Oracle DB in stead.

Comment: If you are trying to view SQL Server data from Oracle, then you don't really have an option. You would need a licensed version of Oracle.

Comment: Gerard, the task is to write data into the Microsoft SQL Database